# Signing in to an application with ws-federation from front-end application

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, ws-federation

I have two applications, one web-api application (y.x.com) and a front-end application (z.x.com). To authenticate the user who visits z.x.com I use ws-federation or microsoft live login following the web api template code provided by visual studio 2015. If I talk directly to the web api application (y.x.com) from my browser, postman, fiddler or anything similar the authentication works fine but if I try to sign in from the front-end application I get `error: invalid_request` (status 400).

Now I wonder if it should be possible to sign in from application z.x.com by calling `y.x.com/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Federation&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http://y.x.com`.

My startup.auth in y.x.com looks like this

```
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        var wsOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/afd2d5a6-bdb1-43f8-a42b-83ec49f1f22d/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
            Wtrealm = "http://y.x.com/",
            Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
        };
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsOptions);
```

I can provide more code but I'm mostly interested in if should work at all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. After som digging and help it turns out that in the web-api template there is a method named `ValidateClientRedirectUri` in the class `ApplicationOAuthProvider`. If I change that method to

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
{
    context.Validated();
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

and then from my front end application I can now have any return url I want, making it possible to sign in from the front-end application via the web-api application to an external source.